# Building multiview/mosaic of 4 input UDP streams and output to UDP stream

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, udp

I was able to find a few examples online of using FFMPEG to build a 2x2 mosaic and have it working pretty well with four input UDP streams.

The issue is when playing back, input 1, 2 and 3 stop playing after a few seconds and stream 4 continues without issue. Can someone help me figure out why this is happening. I would like all streams to play without stopping. See command below:

```
ffmpeg -i "udp://239.86.0.2:3030" -i "udp://239.86.0.3:3030" -i "udp://239.86.0.4:3030" -i "udp://239.86.0.5:3030" -f lavfi -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540,setsar=1[upperleft];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540,setsar=1[upperright];[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540,setsar=1[bottomleft];[3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540,setsar=1[bottomright];[upperleft][upperright]hstack[topbase];[bottomleft][bottomright]hstack[bottombase];[topbase][bottombase]vstack[base]" -map [base] -map 4 -f mpegts udp://239.1.1.1:1234
```